# Cannot add an entity that already exists in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, instance

I am having this problem...Tried to figure out this,and searched out,but the solutions out there but cant fix this,some reply would be helpful.thankyou

```
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Rptr.Items)
        {
            Label LblIncdntID         = (Label)item.FindControl("LblIncdntID");

            Guid g = new Guid(LblIncdntID.Text);

            _IncidentType.INCIDENTREPORT_ID = INCIDENTREPORT_ID;
            _IncidentType.INCIDENTREPORT_INCIDENTTYPE_ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            _IncidentType.INCIDENTTYPEID = g ;
            db.INCIDENTREPORT_INCIDENTTYPEs.InsertOnSubmit(_IncidentType);
            db.SubmitChanges();

        }
```

Comment: it's because of your primary key , what is your primary key ?

Comment: _IncidentType is defined out of foreach? you should defined into foreach. and your primary key should be indentity

Comment: what's the exception do you got??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using InsertOnSubmit, you should also have a:

```
_IncidentType = new IncidentReport();
```

In the foreach loop, before all the property assignments.  The context hangs on to entities inserted (and associates certain metadata to the entity) and probably sees the mismatch.